# REST JAX RS : Jersey : How to read pathparam of root resource in sub resource?

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to read the root resource path param in a sub resource file, but I am getting an error. Please Help me.

The way I am following is :

Root resource Service:

```
@Path("/{messageId}/comments")
public CommentResource getCommentResources(){
    return new CommentResource();
}
```

Sub resource code:

```
@Path("/")
public class CommentResource {

    private CommentDAOImpl commentDaoObject = new CommentDAOImpl();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ArrayList<Comment> getAllCommentsForAMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long messageId){
        return commentDaoObject.getAllCommentsForMessage(messageId);
    }

    @Path("/{commentId}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Comment getCommentForAMessage(@PathParam("commentId") long commentId, @PathParam("messageId") long messageId){
        return commentDaoObject.getCommentForMessage(messageId, commentId);
    }
}
```

While reading the "messageId" path param in sub resource I am getting the error:

> Error: @PathParam value 'messageId' does not match any @Path annotation template parameters of the java method 'getCommentForAMessage' and its enclosing java type 
>    'org.ramesh.jrs.Messenger.resources.CommentResource'.

Can anyone help me resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you want pass a parameter to a resource class you must use the [ResourceContext.initResource method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html#initResource-T-).

This is how to modify your code:

Root resource Service

```
@Path("/{messageId}/comments")
public CommentResource getCommentResources(@PathParam("messageId") long messageId, @Context ResourceContext resourceContext){
    return resourceContext.initResource(new CommentResource(messageId));
}
```

Sub resource code:

```
public class CommentResource {

    private CommentDAOImpl commentDaoObject = new CommentDAOImpl();
    private long messageId;

    public CommentResource(long messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ArrayList<Comment> getAllCommentsForAMessage(){
        return commentDaoObject.getAllCommentsForMessage(messageId);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{commentId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Comment getCommentForAMessage(@PathParam("commentId") long commentId){
        return commentDaoObject.getCommentForMessage(messageId, commentId);
    }

}
```